# How to get step names status of test cases using com4j interface through java

Tags: java

Hi All,

I was successfull in retrieving the step names of each test case by
using the below code.

```
ITestFactory iTestFactory =
        qcconnection.testFactory().queryInterface(ITestFactory.class);

Com4jObject comobjTest = iTestFactory.item(testInstance.testId());

iTest =comobjTest.queryInterface(ITest.class);   
IList steps = iFactory.newList("");

for(Com4jObject testIns: steps){

    IDesignStep destep;
    destep=testIns.queryInterface(IDesignStep.class);      
    System.out.println("stepdescirption"+destep.stepDescription()); 
}
```

I am using the below code to retrieve status of step names

```
Com4jObject SubjectField = (Com4jObject)destep.id();
IStep st=SubjectField.queryInterface(IStep.class);
System.out.println("destep."+st.status());
```

But i am retrieving status of the step as null.

Anyone please help me how to retrieve the status of the steps of each test cases and execute it.

Thanks in Adavance.

Comment: Please Anyone help for the above issue.

Comment: Anyone please help me ...its an important task